# Spring Security back channel SAML SOAP Authentication

Tags: soap, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a Spring Security app that uses SAML.  It is working fine.  I go to a secured page, I get redirected to the IDP, login... success.

Now I want to have the login done "in house" as it were, with no redirection.

I want to have a login page that takes username/pass - then -- well I don't know. :)

Is there anyway to NOT have the user's browser go to the IDP,  either POST the form to the IDP and then redirect back to my app?

I read in the documentation about back-channel SOAP calls, and that sounds like exactly what I want, but I can't find anything on it.  Does anyone have an example of how this would be achieved?